# Symfony 2 Form bindRequest method do not properly bind one-to-many relationship

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, symfony-forms

I'm quite new to Symfony 2 Framework, hence the noobish questions due to immaturity of understanding the inner functionalities of the framework. Basically, I have an embedded forms that is one to many relationship. I have an entity called event which have at least one or more time objects

So here is my entity classes

Event.php

```
<?php namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity; use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



> /**  
>      * @ORM\Entity  
>      * @ORM\Table(name="events")  
>      */ 
>     class Event {
> 
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id
>      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
>      */
>     protected $id;
> 
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
>      */
>     protected $eventTitle;
> 
>     ....   
> 
>     /**
>     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Time", mappedBy="event", cascade={"all"})
>     */
>     protected $eventTimes; 
> 
>     ......  
> 
>     public function __construct() {
>         $this->eventCategories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
>         $this->eventTimes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
>     }
> 
>     ...... setter + getter stuff ....
> 
> 
> 
>     /**
>      * Add eventTimes
>      *
>      * @param KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time $eventTimes
>      */
>     public function addTime(\KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time $eventTimes)
>     {
>         $this->eventTimes[] = $eventTimes;
>     }
> 
>     /**
>      * Get eventTimes
>      *
>      * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
>      */
>     public function getEventTimes()
>     {
>         return $this->eventTimes;
>     }
> 
>     ......
> 
>     }
```

Time.php

```
 <?php namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**  * @ORM\Entity  * @ORM\Table(name="eventTime")  */ class Time {

     /**
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="eventTimes")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     protected $event;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
      */    
     protected $begin;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
      */    
     protected $end;


    ...... setter + getter stuff


     /**
      * Set event
      *
      * @param KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event $event
      */
     public function setEvent(\KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event $event)
     {
         $this->event = $event;
     }

     /**
      * Get event
      *
      * @return KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event 
      */
     public function getEvent()
     {
         return $this->event;
     }

  }
```

Now when I make the embedded form, I extends the AbstractType in order to make a reusable form classes ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes )

Here is my form classes

TimeType.php

```
<?php

namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class TimeType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('begin')
            ->add('end')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions ( array $options )
    {
        return array (
            'data_class'=>'KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time',
            );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'klikevent_eventbundle_timetype';
    } }
```

and

EventType.php

```
<?php

namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\FeedbackType; use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\TimeType;

class EventType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('feedback', new FeedbackType())
            ->add('eventTitle')
            ->add('eventLocation1')
            ->add('eventLocation2')
            ->add('eventShortDescription')
            ->add('eventDescription')
            ->add('eventFurtherDescription')
            ->add('eventCoverImage')
            ->add('eventImages')
            ->add('eventVideos')
            ->add('eventCategories')
            ->add('eventTimes', 'collection', 
                array ('type' => new TimeType(), 
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                    ))


        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'klikevent_eventbundle_eventtype';
    } }
```

Now whenever I want to process the inputted inputs in the controller, I will call the $form->bindRequest($request) method but it throw me an error of having no setEventTimes () method in the event class

```
Property "eventTimes" is not public in class "KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event". Maybe you should create the method "setEventTimes()"?
```

Which is strange, since the generate:doctrine:entities only generate an addTimes method instead of setEventTimes, I assumed that the intended course of action of the bindRequest method would be to add all the inputted time object to the event object. I am baffled with this error and would be glad to be given help, direction or even hint on what I did wrong

Regards

Edit 1.. Added Controller

Here you go the controller. I only show the relevant controller method as it will be too lengthy if I show everything

```
<?php

namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Subscriber;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Category;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Feedback;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time;

use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\SubscribeType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\FeedbackType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\EventType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\TimeType;

class DefaultController extends Controller<?php

namespace KlikEvent\EventBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Subscriber;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Category;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Feedback;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time;

use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\SubscribeType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\FeedbackType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\EventType;
use KlikEvent\EventBundle\Form\TimeType;

class DefaultController extends Controller{

....


    public function defaultTipsEventOwnerAction( Request $request )
    {
        $feedback_event_owner = new Event();
        $time =  new Time(  );

        $feedback_event_owner->addTime( $time );

        $form_event_owner = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $feedback_event_owner);



        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {


            $form_event_owner->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form_event_owner->isValid()) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($feedback_event_owner);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->setFlash('tips-notice-ok', 'Terima kasih untuk tips');

                $feedback_event_owner = new Feedback();
                $form_event_owner = $this->createForm(new FeedbackType(), $feedback_web);

                return $this->render .....

                );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->get('session')->setFlash('tips-notice-error', 'Maaf, Ada error. Coba lagi');
                 return $this->render .....
            }

        }
        return $this->render .....
    }

......


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller please

Comment: I've edited the question with the controller snippet :D

Comment: Change `addTime` to `addEventTime`

Comment: It throw the same error --> Property "eventTimes" is not public in class "KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Event". Maybe you should create the method "setEventTimes()"?

Comment: As I tried to change that method into setEventTimes() it let me pass the form validation, but then the persisted value in the database have some missing value. The eventTime table have a NULL value in their reference column (event_id Column) to the event table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got this after struggling for days. This is such an ugly hacks

Basically the generate:doctrine:entities were not able to correctly produce the appropriate method for the entity class. This may or may not due to my incorrect usage but then In my particular case, it did not create the setEventTimes () method properly.

So what I did was, create the setEventTimes () method that basically replace the whole collections of eventTimes inside the entity

like this

```
public function setEventTimes( $eventTimes )
{
    $this->eventTimes = $eventTimes;
}
```

Which is different from the method that is generated by the Symfony generate script which is essentially adding Time entity one by one

```
/** THIS IS GENERATED
 * Add eventTimes
 *
 * @param KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time $eventTimes
 */
public function addTime(\KlikEvent\EventBundle\Entity\Time $eventTimes)
{
    $this->eventTimes[] = $eventTimes;
}
```

This has solved the error that Symfony 2 were throwing me earlier.

Upon further inspections, the Time entity do not have a reference to the Event Entity, in the database, the event_id collumn of the time always entered as NULL. So to circumvent this, I added some code to add reference to the event entity in each and every time object entered like the code snippet below before persisting object into the databse

```
            foreach ( $feedback_event_owner->getEventTimes() as $times )
            {
                $times->setEvent($feedback_event_owner);
            }
```

Hope this help anyone that face the same problem like me.

Thanks for @flukey 's effort to help me :D